# correctly overloading the __add__ of a namedtuple

Tags: python, overloading, namedtuple

I'm trying to overload the `__add__` method on namedtuple instances and I'm having a bit of trouble.

The parameters input into my namedtuples are dynamically generated.  Four parameters are always the same and in the same order, but the rest can be anything and in any number.  So I need to be able to dynamically define my namedtuple class factory.  And after I create several instances, I'd like to be able to add them together into a new namedtuple instance, with all the unique parameters together.  But I am having trouble properly overloading the `__add__` method.  It doesn't seem to work.

So for example, if I have 3 namedtuple instances

```
e = Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
m = Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a', param2='b')
t = Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param3='val', param4=10)
```

I'd like to be able to add them like `e + m + t` which returns

`Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a', param2='b', param3='val', param4=10)`

Here is my current code

```
class Row(object):
    ''' Creates a new namedtuple object '''
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' make a new Row instance '''
        default = namedtuple('Row', 'a, b, c, d')
        newcols = set(args) - set(default._fields)
        finalfields = default._fields + tuple(newcols) if newcols else default._fields
        return namedtuple('Row', finalfields)

    def __add__(self, other):
        ''' This is the new add '''
        self_dict = self._asdict()
        other_dict = other._asdict()
        self_dict.update(other_dict)
        new_fields = tuple(self_dict.keys())
        new_row = namedtuple('Row', new_fields)
        return new_row(**self_dict)
```

With this, I can correctly dynamically generate new namedtuples, and instantiate them

```
e = Row()
m = Row(*['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'param1', 'param2'])

e._fields
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
m._fields
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'param1', 'param2')

e2 = e(1, 2, 3, 4)
m2 = m(1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b')

e2
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
type(e2)
__main__.Row

m2
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a', param2='b')
```

but when I add them, my overloaded `__add__` never gets called and I seem to just get a regular tuple object back out

```
w = e2 + m2
print(w)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b')
type(w)
tuple
```

My `__add__` method doesn't seem to be active on my instance objects.

```
Row.__add__?
Signature: Row.__add__(self, other)
Docstring: This is the new add
File:      <ipython-input-535-817d9f528ae7>
Type:      instancemethod

e.__add__?
Type:        wrapper_descriptor
String form: <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'tuple' objects>
Docstring:   x.__add__(y) <==> x+y

e2.__add__?
Type:        method-wrapper
String form: <method-wrapper '__add__' of Row object at 0x122614050>
Docstring:   x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
```

What am I doing wrong?  I also tried subclassing namedtuple('Row', ...), as indicated in the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple, but I couldn't get that to work. I couldn't get it to dynamically change the named parameters.

Here is that failure

```
BaseRow = namedtuple('BaseRow', 'a, b, c, d')

class Row(BaseRow):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_fields = set(kwargs.keys()) - set(cls._fields)
        cls._fields += tuple(new_fields)
        obj = super(Row, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj

e = Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a')
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param1'
```

Comment: That's... contrary to a lot of namedtuple design decisions, and unlikely to turn out well. I recommend just using dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  I am kind of forced to used namedtuples because I'm dealing with results returned by SQLAlchemy, which returns things as KeyedTuples, which is their version of a namedtuple.  So I have to use namedtuple so that my general functions can work with both.  I'm sure this breaks the whole ethos of tuples.

For posterity, here is how I solved it.  Since namedtuple is actually just a function that generates classes, I simply wrote my own function, that will dynamically generate a new namedtuple object, in the same way, and overloaded the `__add__` method to each class that is generated.

```
def mytuple(name, params=None, **kwargs):

    # check the params input
    if params and isinstance(params, six.string_types):
        params = params.split(',') if ',' in params else [params]
        params = [p.strip() for p in params]

    # create default namedtuple and find new columns
    default = namedtuple(name, 'a, b, c, d')
    newcols = [col for col in params if col not in default._fields] if params else None
    finalfields = default._fields + tuple(newcols) if newcols else default._fields
    nt = namedtuple(name, finalfields, **kwargs)

    def new_add(self, other):
        ''' Overloaded add to combine tuples without duplicates '''    
        self_dict = self._asdict()
        other_dict = other._asdict()
        self_dict.update(other_dict)

        new_fields = tuple(self_dict.keys())
        new_row = mytuple(self.__class__.__name__, new_fields)
        return new_row(**self_dict)

    # append new properties and overloaded methods
    nt.__add__ = new_add
    return nt
```

It is used like so

```
# create first version
nt = mytuple('Row', 'a, b, c, d')
e = nt(1,2,3,4)
e
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)

# create second version
nt = mytuple('Row', 'a, b, c, d, param1, param2')
m = nt(1,2,3,4,'a','b')
m
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a', param2='b')

# create third version
nt = mytuple('Row', 'a, b, c, d, param3, param4')
s = nt(1,2,3,4,'stuff',10.2345)
s
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param3='stuff', param4=10.2345)

# add them together
d = e + m + s
d
Row(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, param1='a', param2='b', param3='stuff', param4=10.2345)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__add__` method you defined is a method that is only accessible to instances of class type `Row`.

When you overrode the `__new__` method of your `Row` class, you return an object of type `namedtuple(...)`, not `Row`. Therefore, further manipulation of those objects will not have access to your `__add__` method because they are not `Row`s, they are `namedtuple()`s.

As a @user2357112 mentioned, it seems like you're making things difficult for yourself and may be better off simply using dictionaries. If you need an immutable, hashable type for each of your Rows so you can create sets and use them as dictionary keys, convert your dictionaries to named tuples right before using them that way.